# How to tell when a Kendo Grid.saveAsExcel method has finished exporting it's data to excel

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

How to tell when a kendo grid excel export has finished exporting to excel.

I have a kendo grid which uses has around 9000 rows and around 20 columns.
Due to various circumstances, the export to excel takes around 20-30 seconds to finish. 
I have hooked onto the data source request start event to produce a spinner whilst the request is waiting for a response. This works well for loading the data into the grid and then to disable the spinner, i use the databound event to handle this. The problem is when invoking the kendo grid saveAsExcel method which will fire the requestStart event but will not fire the dataBound event.

```
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: url,
            cache: false
        }
    },
    requestStart: function (e) {
        spinnerService.isLoading(true);
    },
    pageSize: 20,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        buttonCount: 5,
        pageSize: 10,
        pageSizes: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
    },
    serverPaging: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    scrollable: true
})

dataBound: function (e) {
    boundDataToPotReportGrid = true;
    spinnerService.isLoading(false);
}
```

What event should i handle for when a kendo grid has finished exporting it's results to an excel file.

Comment: this documentation may help https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ooxml/workbook/configuration/creator